# Set that contains half of the real numbers

Tags: probability, real-numbers

How would you define a set $S$ for which, for any non-empty interval $(a,b)$, the probability a real number $c \in (a,b)$ being inside $S$ is $\frac{1}{2}$?

This means I'm looking for a set which contains half of the real numbers but is not continuous anywhere (so things like $\{x\in \mathbb{R}\ |\ \lfloor x\rfloor \text{ is even}\}$ would not work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "the probability of a real number $c \in (a,b)$ being inside $S$"?  If you mean that the Lebesgue measure of $(a,b) \cap S$ is $(b-a)/2$, this is impossible by the Lebesgue density theorem.